# Android oreo shows icon inside white round

Tags: icons, geometry, android-launcher, android-8.0-oreo, adaptive-icon

My Android application shows launcher icon inside white circle on Android oreo version.

I would like to show launcher icon as it is like square on oreo device by default.

Gone through various blogs and found that :

1) Mobile user can change icon type from home screen settings screen

> (But that I don't want. I want to display only square by default)

2) Use application target sdk version below 26

> (I want to have latest sdk version targeted and square launcher icon)

I have tried :

1. Adaptive icon with background and foreground drawables (Does not show square icon)
2. Used mipmap folders

Can anyone help me for any solution for the same?

Answer (score 19):

If you want to keep displaying your app icon in a square, you'll have to build your app using Android SDK 25 of less.

If your app is compiled with Android SDK 26 or more, your app icon will appear inside a white round, whether you use the new adaptative icon format or the legacy format.

I advise you to use Android Studio's Image Asset Studio to create an adaptative icon for your app.
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html

For more infos on creating adaptative icon:
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html

*If you want just to update your app icon from legacy:*

Right click your app (in Project tab) -> New -> Image Asset, select Asset type: image and choose your image in Path.

Comment: are you sure about that? I've SDK 27 as target sdk but I didn't get the fancy white square :(?

Comment: It's not a white square but a white round you'd be seeing if you've compiled your legacy icon app with SDK 27

Comment: Not sure why this got down voted, his advice on the Image Asset Studio did the trick for me...thanks!