# How to remove white lines around Android app icon

Tags: android, xamarin.android, icons, android-launcher

I am working on an Xamarin.Android app and noticed the app icon doesn't look right on a Xiaomi Poco F3 smartphone running Android 11.

There is a very thin white line on top, bottom, left and right of the icon. It seems like the square icon was used and cut to fit a circle but it doesn't fit entirely.

See the second to the left app icon with the blue background:

[image]

The app is using the legacy approach for app icons:

Icon dimensions are as recommended: 48 x 48 pixels (mdpi), 72 x 72 pixels (hdpi) and so on...
and look fine on other devices (Samsung Galaxy S5 (Android 6), Pixel 2 (Android 9)).

mipmap folders:

[image]

MainActivity:

```
[Activity(
    ...
    MainLauncher = true,
    Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
    RoundIcon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher_round",
    ...
    )]
```

Target version: Android 11.0 (API Level 30)

Minimum version: Android 4.1 (API Level 16)

No third party launcher installed.

Anyone experienced something similar? Can it be fixed without creating new icons?

Answer (score 2):

Had similar issue on Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro.

For some reason android studio resource manager didn't create mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder. (Screen 1)

[Res screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVC8A.png)

Check if you have one.

For me deleting all icon res and creating new helped. (Don't know why, but rewriting it is buggy. Some are missing during this procedure)

Comment: same here. Your answer helped me to solve the issue.

Comment: This still seems to be an issue, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That is an interesting question. You just have to follow my simple steps down below.

**1. Right-click on the "res"
2. New --> Image Asset**

[image]

**3. On the Asset Studio window, you will find a section called "Scaling"
right below Scaling --> resize.**

[image]

Now you can resize your icon and that is how you can make a white thin layer disappear. I hope this might help Thank you.

Comment: You can set background color same as Icon/Image background color(Blue) @Reepicheep

Comment: This should work , but you have to mention the operation should be done in `Android Studio`,and than migrate all the images to visual studio ,  refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53221631/8187800.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid recreating the icons as it is very time consuming: Downloading Android Studio - there is no Image Asset Studio in Visual Studio 2019, etc.. But it seems resizing / removing of padding is the way to go. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad that I'm able to help.

Comment: If it works consider marking it as answer because it's helpful to others.